# VIsual Studio Code does not highlight error in Keras code

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, visual-studio-code, tf.keras

Update:

settings.json

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/home/winston/anaconda3/envs/gpu/bin/python"
}
```

---

I have code using Keras to train model and then save the trained model.

```
model.save('incepv3_transfer.h5', overwrite=True, include_optimizer=True, save_format='h5')
```

the save_format parameter should not be there as the save() method does not have that parameter
[image]

but the VSC does not provide error message there.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What linters do you have set up to detect this sort of thing?

Comment: hi @BrettCannon I'm new to Python, where can I see the linter?

Comment: Please share all of your `"python"` settings from VS Code (easiest might be copying them from your `settings.json` file).

Comment: hi @BrettCannon updated, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Detection of errors like calling with incorrect arguments are handled by linters. You need to install one and turn them on in VS Code, such as flake8, Pylint, mypy, etc. If you have done this correctly you will end up with a some setting of the form `"python.linting.<linter>Enabled": true`.

Please see the [documentation on linting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting) for details on what linters are supported and which settings to use.

Comment: thanks @Brett, the function I use here is Keras function, how does Pylint knows the parameters in Keras??

Comment: @Franva Pylint will try to analyze the code to figure it out, otherwise it might try to use type stubs if they are provided.